# After installing my files on ubuntu apache server it stops working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a ubuntu server. I installed Apache there, added my files and after that I don't get any error just it can't connect to the address. (For my files I had to enable .htaccess as well). I'll add here the .htaccess, but the error still is there even if I deleted the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

order allow,deny
allow from all
```

I also have a `vendor/autoload.php` there I'm not sure if I have to install something for that to make it work 100%.

Apache error log

```
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487006 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/ -> 
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487042 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(\\w+)$' to uri ''
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487047 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/ -> 
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487050 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(\\w+)+\\/$' to uri ''
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487053 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/ -> 
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487055 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^' to uri ''
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487061 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='EXAMPLE.com' pattern='!^$' => matched
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487065 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='EXAMPLE.com' pattern='!^www\\.' [NC] => matched
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487069 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='offs' pattern='^on(s)|' => matched
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487077 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] rewrite '' -> 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/'
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487081 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.EXAMPLE.com/
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487084 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] escaping http://www.EXAMPLE.com/ for redirect
[Mon Apr 03 18:25:51.487090 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 53934] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:63842] 127.0.0.1 - - [EXAMPLE.com/sid#7fc536e48158][rid#7fc536d8e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/] redirect to http://www.EXAMPLE.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

Comment: It is helpful to include the error messages you receive.

Comment: Have you looked at Apaches' error log? It should be `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: It don't get any error message. Only what I get is `this site cannot be reached`.

Comment: Edited first post for apache error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd suggest to change your .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .? https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]
```

That should do the same you tried to achieve with your config, but in the right order and clean syntax.

Also lost

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

since it doesn't provide any benefit here. Probably you defined a DocumentRoot somewhere and you have to put this 'order,allow'-part into the directory-directive for your DocumentRoot, for example:

```
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"

<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If there are errors or non-functionality left, increase your 'LogLevel' in error.log to warn or even info, restart and check the error.log

Comment: Hey, I think the issue is I'm trying to connect to my site through my VPS IP because I don't have a domain and I think it's caused by the .htaccess file.

Comment: If there are errors or non-functionality left, increase your 'LogLevel' in error.log to warn or even info, restart and check the error.log

Comment: How could I increase my LogLevel?

Comment: Search your main apache conf or eventually it is configured in an `errors.conf` or something like this. Whereever you find `LogLevel` set the value to `info` then restart and retest.

Comment: After doing that, I can see from log that it's trying to access url DOMAIN/var/www/myfile.php

Comment: And is that your correct path? I guess it should look more like /var/www/DOMAIN/myfile.php? Where did you configure your `DocumentRoot`? --> search for it if you don't know^^

Comment: I configured it to /var/www

Comment: I have updated my first post. The page I see is `Server not found`

Comment: Ok, but the error.log shows me that you didn't exchange your htaccess-contents for my suggested version. Did you try that?

Comment: Yep, same thing :/. I think I have to somehow get a domain or something.

Comment: But I'm not sure even if that is the issue

Comment: Wait a second, you don't have domain? What are you trying to call in you browser when testing? oO At some point you have to have a DNS-name and an IP to work with.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue.